# Partial sort Collection with limit and custom Comparator

Tags: java, collections, comparator

I want to sort an ArrayList called imageList like this:

```
Collections.sort(imageList, new MapComparator(Function.KEY_TIMESTAMP, "dsc"));
```

This works fine, but now I want to be able to set a limit (show only the newest 100 images, where the ArrayList is unsorted, so simply creating a sublist won't work) for performance reasons.

My MapComparator class looks like this:

```
class MapComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>
{
    private final String key;
    private final String order;

    public MapComparator(String key, String order)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.order = order;
    }

    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> first,
                       HashMap<String, String> second)
    {
        String firstValue = first.get(key);
        String secondValue = second.get(key);
        if(this.order.toLowerCase().contentEquals("asc"))
        {
            return firstValue.compareTo(secondValue);
        }else{
            return secondValue.compareTo(firstValue);
        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to implement that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to sort your last 100 items in your array list only?

Comment: As a general remark, don't build things like reversing order into your comparator. Just use the `reversed()` method on the comparator interface to reverse the order.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko you certainly have to look at the whole collection; you don't have to *sort* the whole collection, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of an official name for this kind of problem, but it does occur reasonably frequently, and it's often called something like a top-*k* or greatest-*k* problem.

You certainly have to process all the elements in the input, because the last element might belong in the "top *k*" set and you don't know until you've processed every last element. However, you don't have to sort the entire input. Doing something like sorting and then taking a sublist, or with a stream, calling `sorted()` followed by `limit()`, can potentially be very expensive, since with N input elements, sorting is O(N log N). However, it's possible to reduce the time complexity to O(N) simply by keeping track of the greatest *k* elements seen so far as you run through the list.

Guava has a Collector that does exactly this: [Comparators.greatest(k, comparator)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Comparators.html#greatest-int-java.util.Comparator-).

If you don't want to use Guava, it's not too difficult to build your own collector that's more-or-less equivalent. A `PriorityQueue` is quite a useful for this purpose. Here's a first cut at it:

```
static <T> Collector<T,PriorityQueue<T>,List<T>> topK(int k, Comparator<? super T> comp) {
    return Collector.of(
        () -> new PriorityQueue<>(k+1, comp),
        (pq, t) -> {
            pq.add(t);
            if (pq.size() > k)
                pq.poll();
        },
        (pq1, pq2) -> {
            pq1.addAll(pq2);
            while (pq1.size() > k)
                pq1.poll();
            return pq1;
        },
        pq -> {
            int n = pq.size();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T[] a = (T[])new Object[n];
            while (--n >= 0)
                a[n] = pq.poll();
            return Arrays.asList(a);
        },
        Collector.Characteristics.UNORDERED);
}
```

This uses a `PriorityQueue` as an intermediate data structure. As elements are added, the smallest element is trimmed off when the queue exceeds *k* in size. At the end, the elements are pulled from the queue and put into a list in reverse order, so the resulting list is sorted highest to lowest.

For example, given a `List<Integer>` containing

```
[920, 203, 880, 321, 181, 623, 496, 576, 854, 323,
 339, 100, 795, 165, 857, 935, 555, 648, 837, 975]
```

one can do

```
List<Integer> out = input.stream()
                         .collect(topK(5, Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

resulting in

```
[979, 936, 890, 875, 831]
```

---

As an aside, it's possible to create a map comparator much more simply by using the combinator methods in the `Comparator` class. For example, suppose your input looks like this:

```
    List<Map<String, String>> input =
        List.of(Map.of("name", "map1", "timestamp", "00017"),
                Map.of("name", "map2", "timestamp", "00192"),
                Map.of("name", "map3", "timestamp", "00001"),
                Map.of("name", "map4", "timestamp", "00072"),
                Map.of("name", "map5", "timestamp", "04037"));
```

You can easily sort the maps by timestamp like this:

```
    input.stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(map -> map.get("timestamp")))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or collect them into a list, or sort-in-place using `sort(comparator)`, or whatever. You can reverse the sort by doing:

```
    input.stream()
         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(map -> map.get("timestamp"), Comparator.reverseOrder()))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output of the latter will then be:

```
{name=map5, timestamp=04037}
{name=map2, timestamp=00192}
{name=map4, timestamp=00072}
{name=map1, timestamp=00017}
{name=map3, timestamp=00001}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this elaborate answer!

Comment: @StuartMarks this is nice, 1+, but a few remarks if you don't mind... 1) why isn't the finisher as simple as `ArrayList::new` 2) should it also report `SORTED` if `Comparator.naturalOrder()` would have been used (I wonder if that is available for detection though or even worse `Comparator.naturalOrder().reserved().reversed()` - but out of scope here probably)...

Comment: @Eugene Sure, no prob. 1) The ArrayList copy constructor will *iterate* over the provided collection to get the elements, and PriorityQueue doesn't iterate in sorted order. A PQ can only sort destructively, by removing or polling the head of the PQ repeatedly. 2) `SORTED` is a Spliterator characteristic, not a Collector characteristic. I specified `UNORDERED` because the intermediate storage (the PQ) doesn't guarantee preservation of the order of elements that compare equals.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sorted `Stream`:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> newestImages = 
    imageList.stream()
             .sorted(new MapComparator(Function.KEY_TIMESTAMP, "dsc"))
             .limit(100)
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, this will require processing all the elements in your `List`. You can't avoid that if you want sorted output.

Comment: So does this still sort the whole collection or does it "stop" once the best 100 results are found?

Comment: @frizzle It sorts the whole collection, since without processing the whole collection you can't determine the top 100 newest elements. It can't "stop" once the best 100 results are found, since it doesn't know if they are the best 100 results before going over the whole collection.

Comment: Worth noting that in general you can do better -- sorting a list of length N is NlogN, but extracting the top 100 is Nlog100. Easy enough to accomplish with a quicksort-like recursive partition, because you only have to recurse along one of the two branches after a partition.