# Why cant i sort in a reverse order in this code?

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I was trying to sort this `ArrayList<Person>` in a reverse order but this does not compile

```
    List<Person> newList = arrayList.stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder(Person::getAge)) //Error
                .limit(3)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    newList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Is there any other way to sort streams in a reverse order?

Comment: `Comparator.reverseOrder()` doesn't expect an argument, that's why your solution doesn't work.

Comment: are you trying this in a text editor? if not, there surely is a _very_ descriptive error message from the compiler in the IDE of your choice

Comment: sugestão para leitura: [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: The [comment by Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57095585/why-cant-i-sort-in-a-reverse-order-in-this-code#comment100713049_57095619) is worth being elaborated here: The sequence of `sorted(...).limit(3)` might have drawbacks. If you have a list of 10000000 elements and want to obtain the top 3 of them, then *sorting* the 10000000 elements is just a waste of time. There are more elegant solutions for obtaining the "top 'k' elements" when 'k' is much smaller than the size of the input.

Comment: [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51851846/2711488)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the correct way to use it:

```
.sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed())
```

Comment: `limit.sorted` vs `sorted.limit` is _not_ the same thing, though.

Comment: if you really want to suggest a _better_ solution then using a heap structure with only 3 elements inside it, would be a better choice for large inputs.